# Magento2 disaalow URL with /catalog/product/view/

Tags: magento2

I have created a module that omits the category path from the product URL to access the product page, I want to do the same thing for `example.com/catalog/product/view/id/10871/s/bongs.html` redirect on `example.com/bongs.html`

Comment: Do you mean that when the customer visits example.com/catalog/product/view/id/10871/s/bongs.html, you would like to redirect to example.com/bongs.html?

Comment: Yes, correct want to redirect example.com/bongs.html

Answer (score 0):

For these, you can disable the option "Use Categories Path for product Urls" from store configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine optimization. I hope it will be useful as per your requirement.